# Execute file from within ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Pathname` that points to a ruby file.

How do I execute that file from with in another ruby script.

I am looking for something like:

```
Kernel.execute(pathname)
```

It needs to share memory so the solution must run the file within the MRI process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 load pathname
```

The difference between `load` and `require` is with `load`, the file will always be executed. With `require`, it will be executed only once.

Answer (score 1):

Then you simply need [Kernel#require](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require) method:

```
require pathname
```